# No data is inserted in my function with postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgresql, I write a function that want to insert some data by selecting from another table,

The pseudo  code is as follows:

```
function func_insert(vi_code integer)
declare
begin
  insert into table_b(a1, b1, c1,) select a1,b1,c1 from table_a where a1 >= vi_code;
end;
```

There are two ways to call this function:

1. `select func_insert(100);` There is `no` data inserted into table_b
2. `call func_insert(100);`  data is inserted into table_b successfully.

I would ask why no data is inserted with `select func(...)`, but data is inserted successfully with `call func(...)`

Comment: Because your pseudo code does not match reality.  Reality being you did `CREATE PROCEDURE ...`. The docs [User defined procedures](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xproc.html) spell it out.

Comment: The key point that I don't understand is when I run `select func`, the func's body is executed...Should the func run the statements in the function body even I use select to run the function?

Comment: In your question you say `select func()` does not work. You are going to need top provide more information. **Add as text update to question text**: 1) The actual complete function/procedure code. 2) Postgres version and whether it is the community version or a fork. 3) The client being used to run the query.

Comment: Another thought, do you have more then one form of `func_insert()`? In `psql` do `\df func_insert* to verify.

Comment: You can only run a function with a `select`, a procedure only with a `call`. If it's a procedure, `select` will fail saying so. If it's a function, `call` will fail informing about the mismatch. If you have both a function and a procedure with matching signatures, both `call` and `select` will fail, saying the routine isn't unique. To clarify the calling/selecting behaviour, you need to share the full function and procedure signatures along with how exactly you invoke them, including parameters - and the error message, if you get one. To debug internal logic, provide a reproducible example.

Comment: [Here are some tests](https://dbfiddle.uk/sKe-f1Dn) showing how Postgres responds to mixing procedures, functions, selects and calls.

Comment: @adrian-klaver，thanks anyway，I have got the answer from ChatGPT，clearly explained

Comment: @Tom Well, good luck on your endeavours. From what I'm seeing, when given your question, ChatGPT answers it with the usual amount of hard drugs, coming up with colourful, serious-sounding descriptions and *clear explanations*, mostly plain untrue and unreproducible, and supporting it with an example that's neither logically nor syntactically valid. It's claiming you can `call` a function and `select` a procedure (as demonstrated above, you can't) and it's drawing some strange transaction-related distinction between procedures and functions and how you choose to call them.

Comment: When asked to clarify the weird claims, it went on to argue PostgreSQL doesn't even have a `call` statement and that *procedure* is just PG jargon for a *function*, adding more fairytales about how all of this works. It's as if it saw a Van Gogh of the PostgreSQL documentation, from very far away and through a kaleidoscope. I can only hope what it told you isn't as insane as what I got.

Comment: @Tom. Then create an answer below with that information. I would be interested in how you can use both `CALL` and `SELECT` on a  function.